# How should I use the propositional logic rules for → and ↔?

Tags: symbolic-logic

My question is how should I use the propositional logic rules for → and ↔ (although other rules may be required) to prove the following:

1. A → B, B → C ⊢ (AvB)  → C
2. A ↔ B ⊢ ¬A ↔  ¬B

Please use the language of propositional logic.

Comment: Which of the *various* propositional logic proof systems are you using?

Comment: For the first one, use [Disjunction elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunction_elimination).

Answer (score 1):

> Below are proofs for each problem. 
>   [image: Here is a proof]

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer to your first question using conditional proof.  If you're unfamiliar with it, conditional proof is a proof method in PL that allows you to assume the antecedent of a conclusion (assuming, of course, that the main operator of your conclusion is a conditional), and allows you to derive a conditional whose consequent is whatever you can deduce within the scope of your assumption.  This is what's going on on lines 4-6.  Notice the indentation - by convention, we indent whatever follows from our assumption, only returning to the non-indented position when we discharge our assumption by deriving the conditional (again, a conditional whose antecedent == whatever you've assumed).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The question is how to use propositional logic rules for → and ↔  to prove the following:

> 1. A → B, B → C ⊢ (AvB) → C
> 2. A ↔ B ⊢ ¬A ↔ ¬B

The first proof illustrates the use of the conditional (→). On the first two lines of a natural deduction proof list the two premises, *A → B* and *B → C*. To show the conditional, *(AvB) → C*, assume the antecedent of the conditional, *(AvB)*, and derive the consequent, *C*.

Can one derive the consequent from the two premises and that assumption? Since the antecedent is a disjunction we consider two cases, *A* and *B*.

For the *A* case, we use the first premise, *A → B*, to derive *B* using conditional elimination. We can use *B* and the second premise to derive *C*.

For the *B* case, we can use the second premise, *B → C*, to derive *C* using conditional elimination.

Since we were able to derive *C* from both of those cases we can use disjunction elimination and derive *C*. But then we can use conditional introduction to derive what we want: *(AvB) → C*.

---

For the second proof we have a biconditional as a premise, *A ↔ B*. We want to derive *¬A ↔ ¬B*. We will create two subproofs to show this. First, we will show that *¬A* implies *¬B*. That will allow us to derive *¬A → ¬B*. Then we will assume *¬B* and derive *¬A*. That will allow us to derive *¬B → ¬A*. With those two subproofs we can derive what we want, the biconditional, *¬A ↔ ¬B*.  Here are the details for that using the proof checker associated with *forallx*, both linked below:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

P. D. Magnus, Tim Button with additions by J. Robert Loftis remixed and revised by Aaron Thomas-Bolduc, Richard Zach, forallx Calgary Remix: An Introduction to Formal Logic, Winter 2018. http://forallx.openlogicproject.org/